# Transform rotate height

Tags: css, css3

Как определить размер области объекта после CSS трансформации. То есть, если использовать `rotate(-45deg)` объект будет развернут, но как мне определить высоту блока, чтобы объект не наезжал на вышестоящие или ниже стоящие объекты?

Comment: Подойдут любые варианты, включая js.

Comment: Используйте элемент **padding** для ваших стилей - [**инфо W3**](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Если делаете объекту `rotate(-45deg)`, можно там же задать высоту в значение гипотенузы этого объекта. То есть

Пример кода с использованием `stylus`:

```
sqrt(x)
  return math(x, 'sqrt')

.rot-object
  width w:20px
  height h:40px

.rot-object
  transform rotate(-45deg)
  height sqrt(w*w + h*h)
```

(https://stackoverflow.com/a/21196698)

Ну, или просто вручную считаете корень квадратов сумм ширины и высоты того объекта и в блоке с `rotate` задаете новую высоту.
Попробуйте так, надеюсь, поможет.